# --from-beginning parameter is not working in kafka-console-consumer.sh but --offset 0 --partition 0 works

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying consume the messages in kafka topic using below command. But it is not working.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server BROKER_URL --topic TOPIC_NAME --from-beginning
```

My colleague used the below query and it is working.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server BROKER_URL --topic TOPIC_NAME --offset 0 --partition 0
```

I'm not sure about the what is the difference between the 2 commands and why the second one is working but not first.

Comment: I tried both commands... It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: What does it mean not working? There is some error or message are not consumed?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Regarding the difference, with the first one, your consumer is joining a consumer group (with a auto generated name) and it starts to get messages from all partitions in the TOPIC_NAME. With the second one, it's using a seek at the beginning of just the partition 0 of the TOPIC_NAME so if it has more partitions, the consumer will not receive messages from them.

Comment: When I say it is not working I mean the command is not fetching any records. While the command is running, the topic is having 8 messages but not retrieving any records at all. I sent new messages  but that is also not retrieved.

Comment: You could try another tool, like Kafkacat https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat  But, these commands work for me too. In any case, you've not said what versions of Java, Kafka, or your Host OS are (in other words, sounds like a problem with your machine)

Answer (score 2):

One reason why this could happen is if the consumer is part of a consumer group. In which case, an offset is established for the consumer group and --from-beginning will not go back to offset 0. However, in the command presented above, I don't see any mention of the (--group) consumer group in the command. Anyway, like other mentioned, the --from-beginning works for stand-alone consumers every time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).